# MonetDB: Enumerate groups of rows based on a given "boundary" condition

Tags: sql, grouping, monetdb

Consider the following table:

```
id  gap  groupID
 0  0    1
 2  3    1
 3  7    2
 4  1    2
 5  5    2
 6  7    3
 7  3    3
 8  8    4
 9  2    4
```

Where `groupID` is the desired, computed column, such as its value is incremented whenever the `gap` column is greater than a threshold (in this case 6).  The `id` column defines the sequential order of appearance of the rows (and it's already given).

Can you please help me figure out how to dynamically fill out the appropriate values for `groupID`?

I have looked in several other entries here in StackOverflow, and I've seen the usage of `sum` as an aggregate for a window function.  I can't use `sum` because it's not supported in **MonetDB** window functions (only `rank`, `dense_rank`, and `row_num`).  I can't use triggers (to modify the record insertion before it takes place) either because I need to keep the data mentioned above within a stored function in a local temporary table -- and trigger declarations are not supported in MonetDB function definitions.

I have also tried filling out the `groupID` column value by reading the previous table (`id` and `gap`) into another temporary table (`id`, `gap`, `groupID`), with the hope that this would force a row-by-row operation.  But this has failed as well because it gives the `groupID` **0** to all records:

```
declare threshold int;
set threshold = 6;
insert into newTable( id, gap, groupID )
        select A.id, A.gap, 
            case when A.gap > threshold then 
                (select case when max(groupID) is null then 0 else max(groupID)+1 end from newTable) 
            else 
                (select case when max(groupID) is null then 0 else max(groupID) end from newTable) 
            end
        from A
        order by A.id asc;
```

Any help, tip, or reference is greatly appreciated.  It's been a long time already trying to figure this out.

BTW: Cursors are not supported in MonetDB either --

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the group using a correlated subquery.  Simply count the number of previous values that exceed 6:

```
select id, gap,
       (select 1 + count(*)
        from t as t2
        where t2.id <= t.id and t2.gap > 6
       ) as Groupid
from t;
```

Comment: This answers works as a wonder.  Just as a side note, in MonetDB, the `from` clause requires the `as` keyword to create the table alias, i.e. `from t as t2`

Comment: @YoungMin . . . Interesting.  I thought MS Access was the only database that required `as` in the `from` clause.